# Why is present() not resolved at runtime in Fortran?

Tags: compilation, fortran, overloading

Consider the function

```
integer function add(x,y)
  integer, intent(in) :: x
  integer, intent(in), optional :: y
  
  if (present(y)) then
    add = x+y
  else
    add = x
  endif
endfunction add
```

I looked at this in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Gbcr8c) and it shows that `present()` is evaluated at runtime with a `CMP` instruction.
Why is this not resolved at compile time?
The compiler certainly knows whether the function is called with one or two arguments.

Comment: `if (rnd<5) allocate (y); z = add(x,y)`. At compile time, you can say whether `y` is present or not? That's even when the compiler has full information.

Comment: Your title and you question appear to be opposite. You mean the version in the text?

Comment: @francescalus Yes... sorry about that In your example, `y` is "present" in both cases. In the linked question (the one that makes this duplicate) it explains that the Fortran standard does not separate compile-time/run-time operations. So there may be some compilers that do this at runtime, others at compile-time.

Comment: If `y` is not otherwise allocated in my incomplete snippet the argument is counted as not present in the function. One can easily think of other examples where the compiler cannot determine at compile time whether the argument is present or not.